# How I can solve pyaudio installation problem in (python3.7 64bit)

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

when I am install pyadio through cmd there was genrate error that is

***Collecting pyaudio

Complete output from command "c:\users\this pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\THISPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\

compile:

running install

```
running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7

copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7

running build_ext

building '_portaudio' extension

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools***
```

But i am already install Microsoft visual c++ 14.0

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Super User Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/).  That said, try uninstalling all of your Microsoft visual c++ programs, then reinstalling them as admin.

Answer (score 0):

When we try to install Pyaudio on Windows it gives us lots of dependencies errors.
The best solution i am able to figure out is use conda environment to resove this.
Once the conda environment is setup in Pycharm(IDE) i am using then we can simply install Pyaudio usign Pip command.

pip install PyAudio

Download and Install Anaconda3 using the link below:-
https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

Hope this helps.